# Shiny R: Conditional style for textInput

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I want to change the colour of some `textInput` **labels**, based on a selection from a `selectInput` output.

The idea is to show, what data in new based on another selection for interactive text. The text itself, I have managed (`updateTextInput`). I would like to do something similar for their label as not all `textInput` change.

So, how do I change the colour of the `Pop` textInput based on the colour indicated from the `TagColor` input, and then again, how do I reset the color to its default style?

```
library(shiny)

ui<-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("TagColor", "Color of my Tag",choices=c("Red","Blue",
    "Yellow","Black", "Initial"), 
    selected = "Red", multiple = FALSE),
    textInput("Pop", "Var1", "Test")
  )
)

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {


})


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use javascript to overwrite the CSS class:
To change it to red, the following JS snippet would be used:
`document.getElementById('Pop').style.border = 'solid red"`

So to use it with your input you would write:

`paste0("document.getElementById('Pop').style.border = 'solid ", tolower(input$TagColor) ,"'")`

To include that in your shiny app you can use the `shinyjs` package.

The full app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui<-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput("TagColor", "Color of my Tag",choices=c("Red","Blue",
                                                        "Yellow","Black", "initial"), 
                selected = "Red", multiple = FALSE),
    textInput("Pop", "Var1", "Test")
  )
)

# 

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    observe({
      color <- paste0("solid ", tolower(input$TagColor))
      if(color == "solid initial") color <- ""
      runjs(paste0("document.getElementById('Pop').style.border =
      '", color ,"'"))
    })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Wonderfull! thanks! Just a tiny problem I face with the `runApp(shinyApp(ui,server), launch.browser = TRUE)`, it did not work on mine, but it might just be me.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? `runApp()` does not work, but `shinyApp()`does?

Comment: exactly. It does not work in parallel for me. I deleted the `runApp()` and changed it to `shinyApp(ui,server)`

Comment: oh, strange. I take the browser for having a convenient JS debugging possibility, but for the show case its not necessary; i made an edit :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Just one more quick thing that would probably improve the whole post. If we want to restore the default css style how do we do it!? (should you have an answer on this, I will change the question accordingly). Thanks, Manos

Comment: the question is how do you want to do that? :) as a choice of the selectInput?

Comment: Yes, I think this is perfect based on the existing working example. I also changed the question to reflect your input! thanks again!