# Shiny R: Change border color of selectInput

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs, shiny-reactivity

I am creating a rather reactive app that has a few `numericInput` variables and some `selectInput` variables.

As the variables are quite many and they are used to estimate interventions, I am introducing colours to denote those variables that are different from the default. I have already implemented this with the help of @BigDataScientist in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099818/shiny-r-conditional-style-for-textinput) question. A MWE is presented:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui<-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    numericInput("V1", "MyV1" , value = 5, min = 0, max= 100, step = 0.01),
    numericInput("V2", "MyV2" , value = 23, min = 0, max= 100, step = 0.01),
    selectInput("V3" , "MyV3" , selected = 1 , choices=c("Yes" = 1,"No" = 0))
  )
)
#
server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if(!is.na(input$V1) & input$V1 != 5){color <- "solid #9999CC"}else{color <- ""}                     
    runjs(paste0("document.getElementById('V1').style.border ='", color ,"'"))
    if(!is.na(input$V2) & input$V2 != 23){color <- "solid #9999CC"}else{color <- ""}                     
    runjs(paste0("document.getElementById('V2').style.border ='", color ,"'"))
    if(!is.na(input$V3) & input$V3 != 1){color <- "solid #9999CC"}else{color <- ""}                     
    runjs(paste0("document.getElementById('V3').style.borderColor ='", color ,"'"))
    })
  })
#
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

As you can see in the following figure, my code works for the numeric values, however **it does not** for the select input variable (on an interactive environment at least).

[image: My example]

Now it is not that the condition does not work, it is evaluated and the `runjs` runs.

Additionally, as you can see in the following js snippet, the js command is just fine. There is probably the way to make it reactive (**without a submit button exactly as the numericInput**) that I miss.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>

<p>Click the button to change the style of the H1 element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").style.borderColor = "red";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `selectize.js` so you can do:

```
selectInput("V3" , "MyV3" , selected = 1 , choices=c("Yes" = 1,"No" = 0), 
            selectize = FALSE)
```

This gives an "ordinary" select input.

Next I've tried your code with `color <- "red"` and this works.

Comment: so if it is not solid and without the selectize.js, it works! OK thanks a lot!

it can also be: 
`    if(!is.na(input$V3) & input$V3 != 1){color <- "solid #9999CC"}else{color <- ""}                     
    runjs(paste0("document.getElementById('V3').style.border ='", color ,"'"))`